# Is there a global event in ExtJS for created components?

Tags: events, extjs, window, extjs4.1

I want to implement some kind of taskbar in my ExtJS4.1 application which contains buttons for all floating components like window. If window is created, a button to minimize/maximize should appear in the taskbar.

So, is there a central event which tells me that a (floating) component has been created or has been shown?

Comment: Components don't just create/show themselves, you have to tell them to do so. As such, when you create the component, pass that information onto your taskbar so it knows about it.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I don't want the creator of the component to know the taskbar.

Comment: They don't need direct knowledge of each other, you can have some mediator class in that middle that directs things. It's going to be a whole lot cleaner than trying to listen for every component creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but Ext.ComponentManager has a public property called 'all' which is a collection of all components.  You could add an 'add' listener the same way that onAvailable() does.

```
Ext.ComponentManager.all.on('add', function(map, key, item) {
    // Check if item is a Window and do whatever
});
```